# MySQL .Net Connector - SELECT always returns 0 rows

Tags: .net, mysql, connector

I have a simple SELECT statement:

```
select field1,field2 from table where id='1234';
```

That always works in mysql workbench but in my .Net application always returns 0 rows. I have INSERT and UPDATE statements in the same application that work fine. What gives?

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection(blah blah blah)
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(queryString,con)
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
reader.read() 
Nope.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the apostrophes around the number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am assuming Entlib is being used

Try
    Reader = Con.ExecuteReader(cmd)

For some reason this has to be run this way.